# Greasemonkey & jQuery How do I manipulate an Element I just created?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

So I'm trying to make a little userscript to send data to a server and react to the answer (by manipulating the link I added to the site)

```
jQuery('table.borderlist').after('<a href="#" id="action"><Click here to do derp</a><br />');
```

This works and adds the link to the site now I bind my new element to a click handler using live() (because that seems to be the only way to work with my new link (id=action))
It looks something like this:

```
    jQuery('#action').live('click', function() { 
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: 'id=666',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      url: 'url',
      success: function (j) {
    // in here I want to change the element with id=action but nothing I tried so far seems to work
}});});
```

the basic idea is to do something like this:

```
jQuery('#action').replaceWith('Action successful');
```

problem is that this does not seem to work on elements I've just created using the Greasemonkey Script on any other element it works fine.

Appreciate any hints in the right direction

Comment: Several issues: (1) How are you loading jQuery?   (2) `action` is a poor choice for an id, chances are, more than 1 node has (or gets) that id.   (3) That ajax call is fetching the url, `url`!   Post the complete script.

Comment: (1) jQuery is loaded on the page i want to manipulate, as I am able to manipulate "all" other elements and adding elements works i dont think this is a problem (2) maybe true but as I read in the jQuery API .live() binds the event to all elements that match the id so, I has to work on my element too and not just dont work? I will change the id anyway to see if it solves the problem. (3) that ajax call is fetching a real url in the real script but I edited it out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have soved it now the problem was that the site uses more than one table with class borderlist 2 of them not visible -.-' so that I could not see that the script actually worked ... Now I selected only the right Element and its working like a charm.

Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
jQuery('table.borderlist').after(
    $('<a href="#" id="action"><Click here to do derp</a><br />').click(function(){

    })
);
```

but your example with .live should work as well. are you sure your id #action is unique?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the element, assign it to a variable, like so:

```
testvar = jQuery('table.borderlist').after('<a href="#" id="action"><Click here to do derp</a><br />');
```

Then, you can refer to that element by its variable later:

```
jQuery(testvar).doStuff(foo,bar);
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not replace the new element but the element (table with class borderlist) that I used to place my element, so the actual link "Click here to do derp" is not touched.